# Is it possible to use two layer.bindPopup functions in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have two different layers in a leaflet map. I have one layer in which I would like the popup to return some text from the layer's attributes. They other layer I would like the popup to return an image which I have embedded the link to in the layers attributes. I have successfully implemented both of the layer.bindpopup functions successfully individually but I'm having no luck implementing them together.

```
function onPlot(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
        layer.bindPopup(
            '<img src= "' + feature.properties.Plot + 
            '" "alt="Elk Hunting Success Trends Plot"' + 
            ' height="500" width="500">');
    }
};

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
        layer.bindPopup( 
            '<center>' + feature.properties.Anum + 
            '<br><center> Hunting District: ' + 
            feature.properties.DISTRICT + 
            "<br><center> Elk Hunter Success " + 
            feature.properties.Success +" %");
    }
};

function style (feature,layer){
    if (feature.properties) {
        return  {
            color: feature.properties.color, 
            fillColor: feature.properties.fillColor, 
            fillOpacity: feature.properties.fillOpacity
        };
    }
};

var Plot= new L.geoJson(Plots, {
    onPlot:onPlot
    style:style
}).addTo(map);

var S_2006= new L.geoJson(Success_2006, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    style:style
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 5):

It turns out I just needed to use an else if statement in the onEachFeature function, which uses layer.bindPopup.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
if (feature.properties.Anum) {
    layer.bindPopup( '<center>' +feature.properties.Anum +'<br><center> Hunting District: ' +feature.properties.DISTRICT+ "<br><center> Elk Hunter Success " +feature.properties.Success +" %");
}
else if (feature.properties.Plot) {
    layer.bindPopup('<img src= "' +feature.properties.Plot +'" "alt="Elk Hunting Success Trends Plot" height="500" width="500">');
}
};
```